# Titanium appcelerator : After running constantly application for some times application crashes

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I have developed an application that could would return various location on basis of category that have been selected by the user. It would also display the complete details of selected places as well as well as show it in map. After running application for few times. Randomly it crashes and returns a long list on console. Here is list of error codes that I receive.

```
[ERROR][JavaObject(  615)] Java object reference has been invalidated.
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:2.3.4/GINGERBREAD/123630:eng/test-keys'
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] pid: 615, tid: 625  >>> com.location <<<
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]  r0 00000007  r1 fffffec4  r2 800a9d08  r3 00000000
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]  r4 41b0ae08  r5 00000000  r6 41b0ae08  r7 00000000
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]  r8 408600f0  r9 443a98d7  10 00000001  fp 000002b8
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]  ip 800a4828  sp 443a9868  lr 80052541  pc 8003dc18  cpsr 00000030
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]          #00  pc 0003dc18  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]          #01  pc 0003e47c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]          #02  pc 001180c0  /data/data/com.location/lib/libkroll-v8.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]          #03  pc 0016b214  /data/data/com.location/lib/libkroll-v8.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] code around pc:
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 8003dbf8 0004b55f 0004874a 0004b6d3 0004872e 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 8003dc08 1c0db530 21011c14 2000b083 fd06f014 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 8003dc18 68216828 d0134288 f854f02e d10f2800 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 8003dc28 69206823 699b682c 69a09000 4a084907 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 8003dc38 44799001 2005447a ec02f7d9 fd70f7f9 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] code around lr:
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 80052520 fffffecc 00036be5 0003c42f 4b05b510 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 80052530 20b94905 585a447b 58d00083 ea3cf7c5 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 80052540 46c0bd10 00052088 fffffec4 4b29b530 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 80052550 48291c04 21cb447b 2501581a b083008b 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 80052560 f7ff54d5 6803ffe3 4d246820 90004a24 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] 
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)] stack:
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9828  40935270  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a982c  8004bb61  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9830  002c2a28  [heap]
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9834  41afd298  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9838  405d4f90  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a983c  8003f257  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9840  80086654  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9844  443a9884  
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9848  80086454  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a984c  80048c6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9850  00000001  
[INFO][DEBUG   (   31)]     443a9854  80052631  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access variable which is pointing to object which was removed from memory. Without any additional code it's impossible to say what's wrong. Do you use any global variables and set them to null / undefined at some place?

Comment: I would agree with @daniula . Its a very old post. Can you post the status of this issue here ?